# How to programmatically initiate NSTextFieldCell editing (make it firstResponder)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I have two `NSTableView`s.  On double clicking on  the  `tableview1` the contents of the `tableview1` will be placed in `tableview2`. I would like to edit the new cell in the `tableview2.` Tried the following method.

`- (void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex row:(NSInteger)rowIndex withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)flag`

This does not make the `tableview2` as firstResponder.  The cursor is not in the new cell. I would like to have the cursor in the new cell and start editing the cell.  Please give me some pointers to accomplish this.  Thanks in advance.

How to bring the cursor in the cell of NSTableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the editing started ,`fieldEditor` comes into picture thats why not able to set the `firstResponder`.

Implemented the `textDidEndEditing` delegate of the tableView. It solved the isssue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `NSArrayController` to hold the data of your tables, you could override `rearrangeObjects:`

```
- (void)rearrangeObjects {
    [super rearrangeObjects];
    [tableView editColumn:0 row:[self selectionIndex] withEvent:nil select:YES];
}
```

An additional advantage is that this method also seems to scroll the table down to the newly inserted row.

Comment: of course, in above example, `tableView` is declared as an IBOutlet in the array controller's interface. Drag an array controller in the Interface Builder, set it's class to your subclass of `NSArrayController`, and ctrl-drag from the array controller to the table view to connect the outlet.